# statistical test for 3 response answer satisfied , not satisfied , can't say

Tags: hypothesis-testing

the survey is for different online payment methods from which replies for which different methods they are satisfied, not satisfied , can't say.which test is to be done in this question.

Comment: Without some detail about the purpose of you research it is impossible to say what you might do.

Comment: For which null / alternative hypothesis?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to do, but if your dependent variable is the satisfaction measure, then I think ordinal logistic regression would be a good starting point.  Or perhaps classification trees. Or multinomial logistic. Or random forests. Or a neural network might work best.